# linux -> how to sort in sequence

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel, amos

how can i get the output below in sort sequence order of 1,2,3,10,12 instead of 1,10,12,2,3 ?

```
avi@tech> get  hardwareNumber=    productNumber
========================================================================================================
MO                                                      Attribute         Value
========================================================================================================
hardwareNumber=1                               productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=10                              productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=12                              productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=2                               productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=3                               productNumber 526845
========================================================================================================
```

Comment: Since you have header and footer, I would write a small script which splits the whole output into header part, body part and footer part, then sort the body part according your criterion, and put everything back together for outputting.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the header and footer (you can add them back after sorting)

```
sort -t= -k2 -n file-with-no-header-or-footer.txt
```

which uses `=` as the delimiter, key `2` and `-n` for numeric, produces

```
hardwareNumber=1                               productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=2                               productNumber 526845
HardwareNumber=3                               productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=10                              productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=12                              productNumber 526845
```

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work, is it wrong with my string?
get  hardwareNumber=    productNumber | sort -t= -k2 -n |

Comment: well, "didn't work" does not help to understand your problem. Show input, output, etc.

Comment: still same output as before, I don't have a txt file
hardwareNumber=1                               productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=10                              productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=12                              productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=2                               productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=3                               productNumber 526845